# Combine three data frames into a long form data frame

Tags: r, long-format-data

I am new to R. I know how to combine different time series data frames into one wide form data frame, but need help with combing them one long form data frame.

Each data frame has hundreds of variables, some of them are the same variables over time, but some do not change over time (e.g., gender), and i want to keep them all in the combined data frame, and hopefully i don't need to specify all the variables in the command--is it possible?

```
data 1 (data collected at time 1)

ID   var1  var2  var3  job gender 
 1    1     1     1      2    0
 2    2     2     2      3    1
 3    1     3     3      4    0

data 2 (data collected at time 2)

ID   var1  var2  var3  
 1    3     2     3      
 2    3     1     2      
 3    1     3     3      
 
data 3 (data collected at time 3)

ID   var1  var2  var3  happy income 
 1    1     2     1      1      5
 2    2     2     2      3      1
 3    1     3     3      4      9 

Hope the combine_long data frame looks like this:
Need a new variable called "time" here.

ID   time  var1  var2  var3  job gender happy  income 
 1    1     1     1     1      2    0      1       5
 1    2     2     1     2      2    0      1       5
 1    3     1     1     1      2    0      1       5
 2    1     2     2     3      3    1      3       1
 2    2     1     2     4      3    1      3       1
 2    3     2     4     5      3    1      3       1
 3    1     3     3     4      4    0      4       9
 3    2     2     1     3      4    0      4       9
 3    3     1     3     1      4    0      4       9
```

the var1, var2 and var3 values in the last data frame may not perfectly match the values in the date 1, data 2 and 3 because I am too lazy to match them, but they should be matched.

I already combined them to the wide form data frame which theoretically should be able to transform to be long form with pivot_longer, but I couldn't figure out how to do it either :(  so I figured I could combine them to the long form from the very beginning. Please help.

Comment: Do you need `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);bind_rows(data1, data2, data3, .id = 'time') %>% arrange(ID) %>% group_by(ID) %>% fill(job:income, .direction = 'downup') %>% ungroup`

Comment: what does "job:income," mean here? How do I specify these kinds of time-invariant variables in the codes?

Comment: It means column name to job to column name income in that range or if you don't want to specify column names, can also use `fill(everything(), .direction = 'downup')`

Comment: Your expected output shows some typos i.e. input have var1 as 1, 2, 1, for ID 1, 2, 3 in data1, whereas expected shows 1, 2, 1 for ID 1

Comment: you are right:) the var1, var2 and var3 values in the last data frame may not perfectly match the values in the date 1, data 2 and 3 because I am too lazy to match them, but they should be matched. I am going to try the codes you taught me and keep you posted.

Answer (score 2):

We may use `bind_rows` on those datasets, with `.id` specified as 'time' to create the index column, then we `fill` the rest of the columns with the previous non-NA value per 'ID' (if there are any `NA` values)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(data1, data2, data3, .id = 'time') %>% 
  arrange(ID) %>%
  group_by(ID)  %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = 'downup') %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 9
  time     ID  var1  var2  var3   job gender happy income
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int>  <int>
1 1         1     1     1     1     2      0     1      5
2 2         1     3     2     3     2      0     1      5
3 3         1     1     2     1     2      0     1      5
4 1         2     2     2     2     3      1     3      1
5 2         2     3     1     2     3      1     3      1
6 3         2     2     2     2     3      1     3      1
7 1         3     1     3     3     4      0     4      9
8 2         3     1     3     3     4      0     4      9
9 3         3     1     3     3     4      0     4      9
```

Comment: Q quick question: these variables (var1...income) are numeric, and I do want them to stay numeric. These codes would not change their structure right (because I saw int in the codes)?

Comment: @Susan It will stay numeric as well (assuming these columns are present in a single dataset or if they are in multiple datasets they should have the same type)

Comment: Sorry a follow-up question: how can I further create a new data frame that only contains IDs that have three time points (the time column has three rows meaning they participate in all three time points)?

Comment: @Susan you can select either afterwards or do this before binding i.e. `library(purrr);list(data1, data2, data3) %>% map_dfr(~ .x %>% select(starts_with('var')), .id = 'time')`

Comment: What if I want to select those cases after I have the combined data set? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Susan That will be `bind_rows(data1, data2, data3, .id = 'time') %>% 
  arrange(ID)%>% select(ID, time, starts_with('var'))`

Comment: somehow it doesn't work, the new data frame i created with these codes only has two columns: ID and time.

Comment: @Susan I get the var1, var2, var3, as well `bind_rows(data1, data2, data3, .id = 'time') %>%    arrange(ID)%>% select(ID, time, starts_with('var')) %>% names#
[1] "ID"   "time" "var1" "var2" "var3"`  Can you change it to `dplyr::select` in case it got masked by any other package function

Comment: What does "dplyr::select in case it got masked by any other package function" mean:) I wonder if there is a simpler way to do it? I already have the combine_long data frame, and I only need to create another new data frame based on the current  combine_long, and the new data frame only contains cases whose "time" column has all three rows?

Comment: @Susan `select` is one function that is found in multiple packages.  Suppose you have loaded another package, then the dplyr select would be masked by that package select function and its behavior would be different. In the above code, you need to just change `select(ID, time, starts_with('var'))` to `dplyr::select(ID, time, starts_with('var'))`

Comment: @Susan when you say simple, `select` step seems to be very simple option

Comment: @Susan If you need a conditional filter, then `bind_rows(data1, data2, data3, .id = 'time') %>% 
  arrange(ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% filter(n() == 3) %>% ungroup %>% dplyr::select(time, ID, var1, var2, var3)`

Comment: I am trying to digest the codes...so "filter(n() == 3) %>% " is the one that helps select the cases with three time points, or no?

Comment: @Susan You have three datasets , each having some ids.  when you rbind or bind_rows, it becomes a single dataset.  then you are grouping by id and checking if there are 3 row, then filter those ids.  Suppose if some ids are absent in some of the datasets, this step removes those ids

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Then what do the following codes do? dplyr::select(time, ID, var1, var2, var3)

Comment: @Susan `select` is a function used for selecting the columns from the dataset by specifying the column name., `time` is a column in the dataset, `ID` is a column in dataset, so is var1, var2, and var3, leaving out the rest of the columns.  I hope you understand

Comment: Oh I see, so I don't need these last line of code because I want new data frame to include all other columns, not just these five columns.

Comment: @Susan then you don't need the `%>% select...` step.  I was thinking that you need only 'var' columns

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `bind_rows` we could use `rbindList` from `data.table`.
The second part is from @akrun's code. In this case in might make no sense to introduce another package, but it could help to think of `rbindList`:

```
library(data.table) 
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

rbindlist(list(data1, data2, data3), fill=TRUE) %>% 
  arrange(ID) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  fill(job:income, .direction = 'downup') %>% 
  ungroup ()
```

```
     ID  var1  var2  var3   job gender happy income
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int>  <int>
1     1     1     1     1     2      0     1      5
2     1     3     2     3     2      0     1      5
3     1     1     2     1     2      0     1      5
4     2     2     2     2     3      1     3      1
5     2     3     1     2     3      1     3      1
6     2     2     2     2     3      1     3      1
7     3     1     3     3     4      0     4      9
8     3     1     3     3     4      0     4      9
9     3     1     3     3     4      0     4      9
```

Comment: What does the "ungroup()" mean here? Thanks!

Comment: It just brings your data to an ungrouped status. Because beforehand we grouped with `group_by(ID)`. So unless we say `ungroup()` the data will stay grouped, and this may have an impact of your analysis.